# Add remove update markers with clusters dynamically javascript without re-rendering google maps api reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**INTRODUCTION**

Have checked all of the questions in here and couldn't find a single solution. I don't want to use any packages like google-maps-react etc.
I have a component which creates a map then creates markers on it then i want to add clusters.

```
  // This function creates the map with the coordinates coming from redux.
  createGoogleMap = () => {
  const map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.googleMapRef.current, {
  zoom: this.zoom,
  center: this.coords,
});
 return map;
};
```

// This function is used to create markers initially with the filtered list. filtered list includes
the coords of the events that i want to show on map

```
  eventMarkers = () => {
  const events = this.props.filteredList.filteredList;




  for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
   const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
     <InfoWindowMaps event={events[i]} />
   );
  const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: events[i].lat,
      lng: events[i].lng,
    },
    icon: location,
    map: this.googleMap.current,
  });

  this.markers.push(marker);

  const infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content,
  });

  marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infoWindow.open(this.googleMap.current, marker);
  });
}

};

  componentDidMount() {
   this.googleMap.current = this.createGoogleMap();
   this.marker.current = this.eventMarkers();
   this.createClusters();
  }
```

Now this much works fine, App runs with my current location then according to my current location a filteredlist is generated which is passed to the component then a map is initialized with the center coords of my current location and with the markers near my current location.

Now when the map is moved a dispatch function is called which updates the filter state in my app with the new center value of the map (basically center value is used to determine near by locations).

```
handleMove = () => {
let newFilter = this.props.filters;

new window.google.maps.event.addListener(
  this.googleMap.current,
  "dragend",
  (c) => {
    let newCenter = this.googleMap.current.getCenter();
    newFilter.locationLat = newCenter.lat();
    newFilter.locationLng = newCenter.lng();

    this.props.setFilter(newFilter); // Dispatch function which updates the filter with new center 
    map value which is used for filteredlist of near by locations
  }
);
```

};

Now the problem comes here, whenever filters are updated my filteredlist gets updated as well (Remember filteredlist is the final values for markers which are shown on map). Now what i want is the new filteredlist markers on map and removing any which doesn't exist in the filteredlist anymore. For that i am doing this following solution

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

Right now when my redux is updated with new filteredList my `componentDidUpdate` runs. In here i am calling the `eventMarkers()` function like i did in `componentDidmount`. In this function it first removes the marker from the map then set the array to empty. Now this method is used everywhere but i don't think this is a good solution because basically i removes my locations then render again then remove then render. Now this removing markers is everywhere even in the google docs but this thing causes problem with my clusters. See i made the clusters with the markers when componenDidMount now when my component updates with new markers then new clusters are made but the previous ones still remains on the component. I even tried to use `this.clusterers.removeMarkers(this.clusterers.getMarkers());` in componentDidUpdate before creating clusters but it is makes it even more buggy so i deleted it

```
createClusters = () => {
   this.clusterers = new MarkerClusterer(
     this.googleMap.current,
     this.markers,
     {
       imagePath:
         "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
     }
   );
 };


   componentDidUpdate() {
     this.eventMarkers();
     this.createClusters();
    }
```

**PROBLEMS AND DESIRED SOLUTION**

Problem is the clustering. When i use the following code in eventMarkers() function it makes the cluster but the markers are changing again and again so its count is increasing and new clusters are forming again and again. (So i want to know how to clear clusters like i am clearing markers.

When a new filtered list comes in, it removes all the markers then render again but i want the markers to update/delete/add dynamically. Not render every time i move map because eventually my app will have thousands of events.

This is a connected single problem with clusters and markers. I hope i have described it good and i have gone through a lot of code and documentations and questions but couldn't find a single solution that will help me. Please help me out and let me know if more information is needed

Comment: Anything you got ?

Comment: I don't remember now but i remember getting of this issue with a hack not a solution